# Python: Process inside decorator

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Could somebody tell me why on Earth we can't still not use local function with the `multiprocessing.Process` standard libraries ?
We are in 2022 and this problem required copy-pasting code to solve it...

```python
def run_ping_outside():
    ping_on_port('google.com', 1234, timeout=5)


class PingHelperUnitTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_ping_on_port_timeout(self):
        def run_ping_inside():
            self.assertTrue(ping_on_port('google.com', 1234, timeout=5))

        # Don't work
        # process = Process(target=run_ping_inside)
        process = Process(target=run_ping_outside)
        process.start()
```

That is a simple example but the real benefit would be to create a `@timeout` decorator for unit testing
And be able to test the speed of some part of our applications.

```python
def timeout(max_timeout_allowed):
    def _timeout(decorated_function):
        def timeout_wrapper(self=None):
            def timeout_inner(*args, **kwargs):
                arguments = (args, kwargs) if self is None else (self, args, kwargs)
                process = Process(target=decorated_function, args=arguments)
                process.start()
                sleep(max_timeout_allowed)
                done_in_time = not process.is_alive()
                if not done_in_time:
                    process.terminate()
                if self is not None:
                    self.assertTrue(done_in_time, f"Function ran out out time: {max_timeout_allowed} second(s)")

            return timeout_inner()
        return timeout_wrapper
    return _timeout
```

Here a **non working** example of this decorator because we can't pickle a decorated function...

PS: No I can't use `Thread` as we are not able to terminate them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, this is a little bit of a hack, but you could do this by saving a copy of the undecorated function under a new name and changing `__qualname__` so pickle knows where to find the saved version. Then, in the subprocess, the same decorator will run, registering the undecorated function to the same place.

Here's the code:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time
import pickle
import sys


class TimeoutClosure(object):
    def __init__(self, func, max_timeout_allowed):
        self.func = func
        self.max_timeout_allowed = max_timeout_allowed
        self.register_inner_function(func)

    def register_inner_function(self, func):
        prefix = 'old_'
        func_name = func.__qualname__
        saved_name = prefix + func_name
        module_name = pickle.whichmodule(func, func_name)
        module = sys.modules[module_name]
        setattr(module, saved_name, func)
        self.func.__qualname__ = saved_name

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        process = Process(target=self.func, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
        process.start()
        # Note: this is faster than time.sleep(), as it exits early if
        # the function finishes early.
        process.join(self.max_timeout_allowed)
        done_in_time = not process.is_alive()
        if not done_in_time:
            process.terminate()

        if self is not None:
            assert done_in_time, f"Function ran out out time: {self.max_timeout_allowed} second(s)"


def timeout(max_timeout_allowed):
    def inner(func):
        return TimeoutClosure(func, max_timeout_allowed)
    return inner


@timeout(1)
def foo():
    print("Entering foo")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("Leaving foo")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo()
```

Comment: Thanks you @Nick ODell. With your example I was able to make a working decorator with the `unittest.Testcase` class. 
I'll create a new package and push to the pypi

Comment: Oh, cool! Send me a link to it when you're done.

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/duration-check/    
@nick-odell, sorry for the delay but I was very busy at work those days.